# How to add all store categories in admin form input field in form.php of magento

Tags: php, forms, magento

I wants to show all available categories in multi select field in admin form. I have tried but have got an empty multiselect. 
Please help me to solve this.

Folder structure of my Modules Block folder as,

[image]

In Form.php I have created my form fields as,

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Bitwaread_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
/**
 * Init class
 */
public function __construct()
{  
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setId('namespace_module_bitwaread_form');
    $this->setTitle($this->__('Bitwaread Information'));
}  
protected function _prepareForm()
{  
    $model = Mage::registry('namespace_module');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method'    => 'post'
    ));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend'    => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Bitwaread Information'),
        'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'id',
        ));
    }  

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'name',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
        'required'  => true,
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('categories', 'multiselect', array(
             'name'      => 'cat[]',
             'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
             'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Store View'),
             'required'  => true,
             'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
      ));
$form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}  
}
```

Here I am succeed to show store views but I wants to show categories. 
I have created a Category.php file in Model folder as,

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Bitwaread extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{  
    $this->_init('namespace_module/bitwaread');
}  
 public function toOptionArray()
{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $tree = $category->getTreeModel();
    $tree->load();
    $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    if ($ids){
        foreach ($ids as $id){
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
            $cat->load($id);

            $entity_id = $cat->getId();
            $name = $cat->getName();
            $url_key = $cat->getUrlKey();
            $url_path = $cat->getUrlPath();
             $options[] = array(
               'label' => $name,
               'value' => $entity_id
            );
        }
    }

   return $options;
}
}
```

---

This Category.php file run properly when I have added them in system.config as  field.
But when tried to add this to form field its not work.
Please help me where I missed the step.

Comment: Tried this?
http://twincreations.co.uk/magento-get-category-list-as-admin-select/

Comment: @Ranker - I tried. but Have got an error as ' Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Module_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\snehal\storecredit\public_html\app\Mage.php on line 547'

Comment: Make sure you created helper in right directory and use right name of it in the form.

Comment: :( .. No I am still facing the same error. is that so My prepareform() method is in Form.php and not in /Tab/Main.php file?

Comment: Does your helper class extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract?

Comment: I have followed http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified this article.

Comment: yes.. class Namespace_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{ }

Answer (score 0):

You can define helper in config.xml in your module:

```
<helpers>
    <module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </module>
</helpers>
```